# Mircosoft Surface 3 Allow this device to wake the computer grayed out

Tags: powershell, wake-on-lan, microsoft-surface

I have a powershell script that wakes computers on lan (wol) using a magic packet. The script works fine for normal desktops but won't work with Microsoft surface 3 tablets. The device is connected via a standard microsoft usb ethernet dongle. I think the problem is due to the fact that allow this device to wake the computer grayed out under the USB controller

[image]

**Questions**

1. Can I enable this setting? If so how?
2. Does this make a difference to wol not working?

Comment: Did you try first disabling "Allow the computer..." If the device is turned off it can't receive the magic packet ...

Comment: Yes I have tried disabling "Allow the computer to turn off this device to save power" Still not change. 
I've done some research but there seems to be nothing on this.

Comment: Did you check ["Allow this device to wake up the computer" disabled](http://superuser.com/q/223860)?